# How to use NuSMV to witness the man-in-the-middle attack (Needham-Schroeder protocol)?

Tags: encryption, model-checking, nusmv

I have the following simplified public-key Needham-Schroeder protocol:

1. `A → B: {Na, A} Kb`
2. `B → A: {Na, Nb} Ka`
3. `A → B: {Nb} Kb`

where `Na`, `Nb` are the nonces of `A`, `B`, and `Ka`, `Kb` are the public keys of `A`, `B` respectively.

Messages encrypted by a party’s public key can only be decrypted by the party.

> At Step (1), `A` initiates the protocol by sending a nonce and its identity (encrypted by `B`’s public key) to `B`. Using its private key, `B` deciphers the message and gets `A`’s identity.
>
> At Step (2), `B` sends `A`’s and its nonces (encrypted by `A`’s public key) back to `A`. Using its private key, `A` decodes the message and checks its nonce is returned.
>
> At Step (3), `A` returns `B`’s nonce (encrypted by `B`’s public key) back to `B`.

Here is the **main-in-the-middle attack** to the above simplified protocol:

- (1A) `A → E: {Na, A} Ke` (`A` wants to talk to `E`)
- (1B) `E → B: {Na, A} Kb` (`E` wants to convince `B` that it is `A`)
- (2B) `B → E: {Na, Nb} Ka` (`B` returns nonces encrypted by `Ka`)
- (2A) `E → A: {Na, Nb} Ka` (`E` forwards the encrypted message to `A`)
- (3A) `A → E: {Nb} Ke` (`A` confirms it is talking to `E`)
- (3B) `E → B: {Nb} Kb` (`E` returns `B`’s nonce back)

I hope that when the attack was found, a fix was proposed to prevent the attack (`B` sends its identity along with the nonces back to `A`):

1. `A → B: {Na, A} Kb`
2. `B → A: {Na, Nb, B} Ka` (`B` sends its identity along with the nonces back to `A`)
3. `A → B: {Nb} Kb`

The questions are:

1. How can I write an LTL formula and a NuSMV module `eve` to model the attacker and witness the man-in-the middle attack?
2. How to prevents the attack?

> The process of alice(A):

```
MODULE alice (in0, in1, inkey, out0, out1, outkey)
VAR
    st : { request, wait, attack, finish };
    nonce : { NONE, Na, Nb, Ne };
ASSIGN
    init (st) := request;
    next (st) := case
        st = request                        : wait;
        st = wait & in0 = Na & inkey = Ka   : attack;
        st = attack                         : finish;
        TRUE                                : st;
    esac;

    init (nonce) := NONE;
    next (nonce) := case
        st = wait & in0 = Na & inkey = Ka : in1;
        TRUE                              : nonce;
    esac;

    init (out0) := NONE;
    next (out0) := case
        st = request : Na;
        st = attack  : nonce;
        TRUE         : out0;
    esac;

    init (out1) := NOONE;
    next (out1) := case
        st = request : Ia;
        st = attack  : NOONE;
        TRUE         : out1;
    esac;

    init (outkey) := NOKEY;
    next (outkey) := case
        st = request : { Kb };
        TRUE         : outkey;
    esac;
FAIRNESS running;
```

> The process of bob(B):

```
MODULE bob (in0, in1, inkey, out0, out1, outkey)
VAR
    st : { wait, receive, confirm, done };
    nonce : { NONE, Na, Nb, Ne };
    other : { NOONE, Ia, Ib, Ie };
ASSIGN
    init (st) := wait;
    next (st) := case
        st = wait & in0 = Na & in1 = Ia & inkey = Kb       : receive;
        st = wait & in0 = Ne & in1 = Ie & inkey = Kb       : receive;
        st = receive                                       : confirm;
        st = confirm & in0 = Nb & in1 = NOONE & inkey = Kb : done;
        TRUE                                               : st;
    esac;

    init (nonce) := NONE;
    next (nonce) := case
        st = wait & in0 = Na & in1 = Ia & inkey = Kb : in0;
        st = wait & in0 = Ne & in1 = Ie & inkey = Kb : in0;
        TRUE                                         : nonce;
    esac;

    init (other) := NOONE;
    next (other) := case
        st = wait & in0 = Na & in1 = Ia & inkey = Kb : in1;
        st = wait & in0 = Ne & in1 = Ie & inkey = Kb : in1;
        TRUE                                         : other;
    esac;

    init (out0) := NONE;
    next (out0) := case
        st = confirm : nonce;
        TRUE         : out0;
    esac;

    init (out1) := NONE;
    next (out1) := case
        st = confirm : Nb;
        TRUE         : out1;
    esac;

    init (outkey) := NOKEY;
    next (outkey) := case
        st = confirm & other = Ia : Ka;
        st = confirm & other = Ie : Ke;
        TRUE                      : outkey;
    esac;
FAIRNESS running;
```

> The process of main:

```
MODULE main 
VAR
    a_in0 : { NONE, Na, Nb, Ne };
    a_in1 : { NONE, Na, Nb, Ne };
    a_out0 : { NONE, Na, Nb, Ne };
    a_out1 : { NOONE, Ia, Ib, Ie };
    a_inkey : { NOKEY, Ka, Kb, Ke };
    a_outkey : { NOKEY, Ka, Kb, Ke };
    a : process alice (a_in0, a_in1, a_inkey, a_out0, a_out1, a_outkey);
    b : process bob (a_out0, a_out1, a_outkey, a_in0, a_in1, a_inkey);
FAIRNESS running;

LTLSPEC F (a.st = finish & b.st = done)
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You may find useful the tool [`proverif`](http://prosecco.gforge.inria.fr/personal/bblanche/proverif/), in particular the relevant examples in its [manual](http://prosecco.gforge.inria.fr/personal/bblanche/proverif/manual.pdf). (Not an answer relevant to NuSMV, but thematically related).

Comment: @loannis Filippidis Thanks for ur comment. I’ve learned the related topic from some websites, but I still cannot figure out how to “witness” the attack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(note: modeling and verifying the system you have in mind with some other tool (e.g. [`Spin`](http://spinroot.com/spin/whatispin.html) or the [`STIATE Toolkit`](http://st.fbk.eu/technologies/stiate)) would be much more simple.)*

---

**Alice and Bob.**

Here we model the type of `user` that behaves in a honest, transparent manner and that in your use-case can be instantiated as either `Alice` or `Bob`.

As a simplification, i hard-coded the fact that if the `user` is `Alice` then it will initiate the protocol by trying to contact the other entity.

The inputs `my_nonce`, `my_id` and `my_key` define a `user`'s identity, whereas `other_key` and `other_id` represent the publicly available information about the other `user` we want to get in touch with. Inputs `in_1`, `in_2` and `in_k` are just like in your code example, whereas `in_3` is reserved for exchanging the third value used in the **patched** version of the protocol.

A `user` can be in one of five states:

- `IDLE`: initial state, `Alice` will initiate the protocol whereas `Bob` waits for some request.
- `WAIT_RESPONSE`: when `Alice` waits to a response to her `request`
- `WAIT_CONFIRMATION`: when `Bob` waits to a confirmation to his `response`
- `OK`: when `Alice` and `Bob` handshake has been successful
- `ERROR`: when something goes wrong in the handshake (e.g. unexpected inputs)

A user can perform one of the following actions:

- `SEND_REQUEST`:      `{Na, IA} Kb`
- `SEND_RESPONSE`:     `{Na, Nb} Ka`
- `SEND_CONFIRMATION`: `{Nb} Kb`

As a simplification, similarly to your own model, I made output values persistent along several transitions instead of putting them back immediately to `NONE`. In this way, I don't have to add extra variables to keep track of input values before they are resetted.

```
MODULE user(patched, my_nonce, my_id, my_key, other_key, other_id, in_1, in_2, in_3, in_k)
VAR
    state  : { IDLE, WAIT_RESPONSE, WAIT_CONFIRMATION, OK, ERROR };
    action : { NONE, SEND_REQUEST, SEND_RESPONSE, SEND_CONFIRMATION };
    out_1  : { NONE, NA, NB, NE, IA, IB, IE };
    out_2  : { NONE, NA, NB, NE, IA, IB, IE };
    out_3  : { NONE, NA, NB, NE, IA, IB, IE };
    out_k  : { NONE, KA, KB, KE };

INIT
    state = IDLE & action = NONE & out_1 = NONE
    & out_2 = NONE & out_3 = NONE & out_k = NONE;

-- protocol actions defining outputs
TRANS
    next(action) = SEND_REQUEST -> (
        next(out_1) = my_nonce & next(out_2) = my_id &
        next(out_3) = NONE     & next(out_k) = other_key
    );

TRANS
    ((next(action) = SEND_RESPONSE) & patched) -> (
        next(out_1) = in_1     & next(out_2) = my_nonce &
        next(out_3) = my_id    & next(out_k) = other_key
    );

TRANS
    ((next(action) = SEND_RESPONSE) & !patched) -> (
        next(out_1) = in_1     & next(out_2) = my_nonce &
        next(out_3) = NONE     & next(out_k) = other_key
    );

TRANS
    next(action) = SEND_CONFIRMATION -> (
        next(out_1) = in_2     & next(out_2) = NONE &
        next(out_3) = NONE     & next(out_k) = other_key
    );

-- outputs stabilization: easier modeling
TRANS
    next(action) = NONE -> (
        next(out_1) = out_1    & next(out_2) = out_2 &
        next(out_3) = out_3    & next(out_k) = out_k
    );

-- protocol life-cycle
TRANS
case
    -- protocol: end-positions
    (action = NONE &
     state = ERROR)
                        : next(action) = NONE &
                          next(state) = ERROR;
    (action = NONE &
     state = OK)
                        : next(action) = NONE &
                          next(state) = OK;

    -- protocol: send request
    (action = NONE &
     state = IDLE &
     my_id = IA)
                        : next(action) = SEND_REQUEST &
                          next(state) = WAIT_RESPONSE;

    -- protocol: handle request
    (action = NONE &
     state = IDLE &
     in_k = my_key)
                        : next(action) = SEND_RESPONSE &
                          next(state) = WAIT_CONFIRMATION;

    -- protocol: handle response
    -- without patch
    (action = NONE &
     state = WAIT_RESPONSE &
     in_k = my_key &
     in_1 = my_nonce &
     !patched)
                        : next(action) = SEND_CONFIRMATION &
                          next(state) = OK;
    -- with patch
    (action = NONE &
     state = WAIT_RESPONSE &
     in_k = my_key &
     in_1 = my_nonce &
     in_3 = other_id &
     patched)
                        : next(action) = SEND_CONFIRMATION &
                          next(state) = OK;

    -- protocol: handle confirmation
    (action = NONE &
     state = WAIT_CONFIRMATION &
     in_k = my_key &
     in_1 = my_nonce)
                        : next(action) = NONE &
                          next(state) = OK;

    -- protocol: no change state while performing action
    (action != NONE)
                        : next(action) = NONE &
                          next(state) = state;

    -- protocol: no state change if no valid input
    (action = NONE &
     in_k != my_key)
                        : next(action) = NONE &
                          next(state) = state;

    -- sink error condition for malformed inputs
    TRUE
                        : next(action) = NONE &
                          next(state) = ERROR;
esac;
```

We add a very simple `main` module and a simple `CTL` property to check that `Alice` and `Bob` behave in the expected way and are able to complete the handshake in normal circumstances:

```
MODULE main
VAR
    a1 : process user(FALSE, NA, IA, KA, KB, IB, b1.out_1, b1.out_2, b1.out_3, b1.out_k);
    b1 : process user(FALSE, NB, IB, KB, KA, IA, a1.out_1, a1.out_2, a1.out_3, a1.out_k);

FAIRNESS running;


CTLSPEC ! EF (a1.state = OK & b1.state = OK);
```

The output is the following one:

```
NuSMV > reset; read_model -i ns01.smv ; go ; check_property             
...
-- specification !(EF (a1.state = OK & b1.state = OK))  is false
-- as demonstrated by the following execution sequence
Trace Description: CTL Counterexample 
Trace Type: Counterexample 
  -> State: 1.1 <-
    a1.state = IDLE
    a1.action = NONE
    a1.out_1 = NONE
    a1.out_2 = NONE
    a1.out_3 = NONE
    a1.out_k = NONE
    b1.state = IDLE
    b1.action = NONE
    b1.out_1 = NONE
    b1.out_2 = NONE
    b1.out_3 = NONE
    b1.out_k = NONE
  -> Input: 1.2 <-
    _process_selector_ = main
    running = TRUE
    b1.running = FALSE
    a1.running = FALSE
  -> State: 1.2 <-
    a1.state = WAIT_RESPONSE
    a1.action = SEND_REQUEST
    a1.out_1 = NA
    a1.out_2 = IA
    a1.out_k = KB
  -> Input: 1.3 <-
  -> State: 1.3 <-
    a1.action = NONE
    b1.state = WAIT_CONFIRMATION
    b1.action = SEND_RESPONSE
    b1.out_1 = NA
    b1.out_2 = NB
    b1.out_k = KA
  -> Input: 1.4 <-
  -> State: 1.4 <-
    a1.state = OK
    a1.action = SEND_CONFIRMATION
    a1.out_1 = NB
    a1.out_2 = NONE
    b1.action = NONE
  -> Input: 1.5 <-
  -> State: 1.5 <-
    a1.action = NONE
    b1.state = OK
```

---

**Alice, Bob and Eve.**

In order to model our **attack scenario**, we first need to model the `attacker`. This is very similar to `Alice` and `Bob`, only that it has double `inputs` and `outputs` so that it can communicate with both `Alice` and `Bob` at the same time.

Its design is very similar to that of `Alice` and `Bob`, so I won't spend many words on it. As a simplification, i removed any error checking on the `attacker`, since it does not actually have any meaningful reason to fail in the use-case scenario being considered. Not doing so would complicate the code for no good reason.

```
MODULE attacker(my_nonce, my_id, my_key, a_key, b_key,
    ain_1, ain_2, ain_3, ain_k,
    bin_1, bin_2, bin_3, bin_k)
VAR
    state  : { IDLE, WAIT_RESPONSE, WAIT_CONFIRMATION, OK, ERROR };
    action : { NONE, SEND_REQUEST, SEND_RESPONSE, SEND_CONFIRMATION };
    aout_1  : { NONE, NA, NB, NE, IA, IB, IE };
    aout_2  : { NONE, NA, NB, NE, IA, IB, IE };
    aout_3  : { NONE, NA, NB, NE, IA, IB, IE };
    aout_k  : { NONE, KA, KB, KE };
    bout_1  : { NONE, NA, NB, NE, IA, IB, IE };
    bout_2  : { NONE, NA, NB, NE, IA, IB, IE };
    bout_3  : { NONE, NA, NB, NE, IA, IB, IE };
    bout_k  : { NONE, KA, KB, KE };

INIT
    state = IDLE & action = NONE &
        aout_1 = NONE & aout_2 = NONE & aout_3 = NONE & aout_k = NONE &
        bout_1 = NONE & bout_2 = NONE & bout_3 = NONE & bout_k = NONE;

-- protocol actions defining outputs
TRANS
    -- attacker: forward A secrets to B
    next(action) = SEND_REQUEST -> (
        next(aout_1) = NONE    & next(aout_2) = NONE  &
        next(aout_3) = NONE    & next(aout_k) = NONE  &
        next(bout_1) = ain_1   & next(bout_2) = ain_2 &
        next(bout_3) = ain_3   & next(bout_k) = b_key
    );

TRANS
    -- attacker: forward B response to A (cannot be unencripted)
    next(action) = SEND_RESPONSE -> (
        next(aout_1) = bin_1   & next(aout_2) = bin_2 &
        next(aout_3) = bin_3   & next(aout_k) = bin_k &
        next(bout_1) = NONE    & next(bout_2) = NONE  &
        next(bout_3) = NONE    & next(bout_k) = NONE
    );

TRANS
    -- attacker: send confirmation to B
    next(action) = SEND_CONFIRMATION -> (
        next(aout_1) = NONE    & next(aout_2) = NONE &
        next(aout_3) = NONE    & next(aout_k) = NONE &
        next(bout_1) = ain_1   & next(bout_2) = NONE &
        next(bout_3) = NONE    & next(bout_k) = b_key
    );

-- outputs stabilization: easier modeling
TRANS
    next(action) = NONE -> (
        next(aout_1) = aout_1  & next(aout_2) = aout_2 &
        next(aout_3) = aout_3  & next(aout_k) = aout_k &
        next(bout_1) = bout_1  & next(bout_2) = bout_2 &
        next(bout_3) = bout_3  & next(bout_k) = bout_k
    );

-- attack life-cycle
TRANS
case
    -- attack: end-positions
    (action = NONE &
     state = ERROR)
                        : next(action) = NONE &
                          next(state) = ERROR;
    (action = NONE &
     state = OK)
                        : next(action) = NONE &
                          next(state) = OK;

    -- attack: handle request, send forged request
    (action = NONE &
     state = IDLE &
     ain_k = my_key)
                        : next(action) = SEND_REQUEST &
                          next(state) = WAIT_RESPONSE;

    -- attack: handle response, forward undecryptable response
    (action = NONE &
     state = WAIT_RESPONSE &
     bin_k = a_key)
                        : next(action) = SEND_RESPONSE &
                          next(state) = WAIT_CONFIRMATION;

    -- attack: handle confirmation, send confirmation
    (action = NONE &
     state = WAIT_CONFIRMATION &
     ain_k = my_key)
                        : next(action) = SEND_CONFIRMATION &
                          next(state) = OK;

    -- attack: simple catch-all control no error checking
    TRUE
                        : next(action) = NONE &
                          next(state) = state;
esac;
```

Again, we add a very simple `main` module and a simple `CTL` property to check that `Eve` is able to successfully attack `Alice` and `Bob`.. at the end of it, `Alice` thinks to be talking to `Eve` (as it is) and `Bob` thinks to be talking with `Alice` when it's truly talking with `Eve`.

```
MODULE main
VAR
    a2 : process user(FALSE, NA, IA, KA, KE, IE, e2.aout_1, e2.aout_2, e2.aout_3, e2.aout_k);
    b2 : process user(FALSE, NB, IB, KB, KA, IA, e2.bout_1, e2.bout_2, e2.bout_3, e2.bout_k);
    e2 : process attacker(NE, IE, KE, KA, KB,
                          a2.out_1, a2.out_2, a2.out_3, a2.out_k,
                          b2.out_1, b2.out_2, b2.out_3, b2.out_k);

FAIRNESS running;


CTLSPEC ! EF (a2.state = OK & b2.state = OK & e2.state = OK);
```

The output follows:

```
NuSMV > reset; read_model -i ns02.smv ; go ; check_property
...
-- specification !(EF ((a2.state = OK & b2.state = OK) & e2.state = OK))  is false
-- as demonstrated by the following execution sequence
Trace Description: CTL Counterexample 
Trace Type: Counterexample 
  -> State: 1.1 <-
    a2.state = IDLE
    a2.action = NONE
    a2.out_1 = NONE
    a2.out_2 = NONE
    a2.out_3 = NONE
    a2.out_k = NONE
    b2.state = IDLE
    b2.action = NONE
    b2.out_1 = NONE
    b2.out_2 = NONE
    b2.out_3 = NONE
    b2.out_k = NONE
    e2.state = IDLE
    e2.action = NONE
    e2.aout_1 = NONE
    e2.aout_2 = NONE
    e2.aout_3 = NONE
    e2.aout_k = NONE
    e2.bout_1 = NONE
    e2.bout_2 = NONE
    e2.bout_3 = NONE
    e2.bout_k = NONE
  -> Input: 1.2 <-
    _process_selector_ = main
    running = TRUE
    e2.running = FALSE
    b2.running = FALSE
    a2.running = FALSE
  -> State: 1.2 <-
    a2.state = WAIT_RESPONSE
    a2.action = SEND_REQUEST
    a2.out_1 = NA
    a2.out_2 = IA
    a2.out_k = KE
  -> Input: 1.3 <-
  -> State: 1.3 <-
    a2.action = NONE
    e2.state = WAIT_RESPONSE
    e2.action = SEND_REQUEST
    e2.bout_1 = NA
    e2.bout_2 = IA
    e2.bout_k = KB
  -> Input: 1.4 <-
  -> State: 1.4 <-
    b2.state = WAIT_CONFIRMATION
    b2.action = SEND_RESPONSE
    b2.out_1 = NA
    b2.out_2 = NB
    b2.out_k = KA
    e2.action = NONE
  -> Input: 1.5 <-
  -> State: 1.5 <-
    b2.action = NONE
    e2.state = WAIT_CONFIRMATION
    e2.action = SEND_RESPONSE
    e2.aout_1 = NA
    e2.aout_2 = NB
    e2.aout_k = KA
    e2.bout_1 = NONE
    e2.bout_2 = NONE
    e2.bout_k = NONE
  -> Input: 1.6 <-
  -> State: 1.6 <-
    a2.state = OK
    a2.action = SEND_CONFIRMATION
    a2.out_1 = NB
    a2.out_2 = NONE
    e2.action = NONE
  -> Input: 1.7 <-
  -> State: 1.7 <-
    a2.action = NONE
    e2.state = OK
    e2.action = SEND_CONFIRMATION
    e2.aout_1 = NONE
    e2.aout_2 = NONE
    e2.aout_k = NONE
    e2.bout_1 = NB
    e2.bout_k = KB
  -> Input: 1.8 <-
  -> State: 1.8 <-
    b2.state = OK
    e2.action = NONE
```

---

**Patched Alice, Bob and Eve.**

Luckily, I already sneaked the **patched** version of `Alice` and `Bob` in the code that I have already shown. So, all that it remains to do is to check that the patch meets the desired behavior by writing  a new `main` that combines `Alice`, `Bob` and `Eve` together:

```
MODULE main
VAR
    a3 : process user(TRUE, NA, IA, KA, KE, IE, e3.aout_1, e3.aout_2, e3.aout_3, e3.aout_k);
    b3 : process user(TRUE, NB, IB, KB, KA, IA, e3.bout_1, e3.bout_2, e3.bout_3, e3.bout_k);
    e3 : process attacker(NE, IE, KE, KA, KB,
                          a3.out_1, a3.out_2, a3.out_3, a3.out_k,
                          b3.out_1, b3.out_2, b3.out_3, b3.out_k);

FAIRNESS running;


CTLSPEC ! EF (a3.state = OK & b3.state = OK & e3.state = OK);
CTLSPEC ! EF (a3.state = ERROR & b3.state = ERROR);
```

The output follows:

```
NuSMV > reset; read_model -i ns03.smv ; go ; check_property             
...
-- specification !(EF ((a3.state = OK & b3.state = OK) & e3.state = OK))  is true
-- specification !(EF (a3.state = ERROR & b3.state = ERROR))  is false
-- as demonstrated by the following execution sequence
Trace Description: CTL Counterexample 
Trace Type: Counterexample 
  -> State: 1.1 <-
    a3.state = IDLE
    a3.action = NONE
    a3.out_1 = NONE
    a3.out_2 = NONE
    a3.out_3 = NONE
    a3.out_k = NONE
    b3.state = IDLE
    b3.action = NONE
    b3.out_1 = NONE
    b3.out_2 = NONE
    b3.out_3 = NONE
    b3.out_k = NONE
    e3.state = IDLE
    e3.action = NONE
    e3.aout_1 = NONE
    e3.aout_2 = NONE
    e3.aout_3 = NONE
    e3.aout_k = NONE
    e3.bout_1 = NONE
    e3.bout_2 = NONE
    e3.bout_3 = NONE
    e3.bout_k = NONE
  -> Input: 1.2 <-
    _process_selector_ = main
    running = TRUE
    e3.running = FALSE
    b3.running = FALSE
    a3.running = FALSE
  -> State: 1.2 <-
    a3.state = WAIT_RESPONSE
    a3.action = SEND_REQUEST
    a3.out_1 = NA
    a3.out_2 = IA
    a3.out_k = KE
  -> Input: 1.3 <-
  -> State: 1.3 <-
    a3.action = NONE
    e3.state = WAIT_RESPONSE
    e3.action = SEND_REQUEST
    e3.bout_1 = NA
    e3.bout_2 = IA
    e3.bout_k = KB
  -> Input: 1.4 <-
  -> State: 1.4 <-
    b3.state = WAIT_CONFIRMATION
    b3.action = SEND_RESPONSE
    b3.out_1 = NA
    b3.out_2 = NB
    b3.out_3 = IB
    b3.out_k = KA
    e3.action = NONE
  -> Input: 1.5 <-
  -> State: 1.5 <-
    b3.action = NONE
    e3.state = WAIT_CONFIRMATION
    e3.action = SEND_RESPONSE
    e3.aout_1 = NA
    e3.aout_2 = NB
    e3.aout_3 = IB
    e3.aout_k = KA
    e3.bout_1 = NONE
    e3.bout_2 = NONE
    e3.bout_k = NONE
  -> Input: 1.6 <-
  -> State: 1.6 <-
    a3.state = ERROR
    e3.action = NONE
  -> Input: 1.7 <-
  -> State: 1.7 <-
    e3.state = OK
    e3.action = SEND_CONFIRMATION
    e3.aout_1 = NONE
    e3.aout_2 = NONE
    e3.aout_3 = NONE
    e3.aout_k = NONE
    e3.bout_1 = NA
    e3.bout_k = KB
  -> Input: 1.8 <-
  -> State: 1.8 <-a
    b3.state = ERROR
    e3.action = NONE
```

The first property confirms that the attack fails and the *handshake* is not completed for neither `Alice` nor `Bob` because `Eve` does not fulfil it. The second property shows *how* the attack is attempted and how it fails in practice.